# AJAX - Like button redirecting me instead of performing ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a like post system already but my problem was that it reloaded after each like. I am still very new to AJAX and dont really understand how it works, but here is what I am doing.

javascript:

```
$("a.like").click(function() {


    $.post(base_url + "index.php/userprofile/like_post/" + user + "/" + post, { user : user, post : post }, function(data) {

        alert('liked');

    }, "json");

    return false;

});
```

This is supposed to be called on the button click. I can tell this isnt even being called because I don't get an alert.

view:

```
<div class='like'>
    <?php echo anchor('#', 'like', array('id' => 'like')); ?>
</div>
```

controller:

```
    public function like_post() {
    $this->load->model('model_users');
    $this->load->model('model_posts');

    $user = $this->model_users->getUserID($this->session->userdata('username'));
    $post = $this->model_users->parseURL($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 2);

    $this->model_posts->likePost($post, $user);

}
```

I am grabbing the userid and post id and putting them into my function

model:

```
    function likePost($post, $user) {
    $data['user_ID'] = $user;
    $data['post_liked'] = $post;

    $insert = $this->db->insert('user_post_likes', $data);
    return $insert;
}
```

When I run this it actually takes me to localhost/musiclear/# instead of skipping over that and doing the ajax call. Im thinking its just not linking correctly or maybe something is wrong with the javascript but im really not sure. This has been bothering me for a while so some help would be great! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're using jquery to select `$("a.like")`, which is an a element with class of `like`. However, according to your markup, the `like` class is attached to your like buttons parent `div`, not to the `a`. As such, I suspect your jquery is not matching the element correctly.

You can test this in your browser console by inputting the jquery selector.

`$("a.like")`

If your element is returned, then your selector is selecting correctly. If you get an empty set, you're not selecting anything.

Based on your markup, I would suggest using the following selector:

`$(".like > a")` (Select child `a` elements of elements with the `like` class)

Comment: That was my initial problem

Comment: I can't quite identify the problem, however this [simplified rebuild](http://jsfiddle.net/zu495136/3/) appears to work fine.

Comment: Playing around a bit, it seems likely that you have an error in your .click function. If you get an error during this portion, the function will abort before the return false, thus causing the link to be loaded with a full page refresh. Check your variables and the file location.

Comment: Where does the data get passed in to those variables? Im very new and have mostly just been copying other codes for the ajax stuff

Comment: I don't think your post is optimized for a simple like. It's unlikely that you would need a variable for the URL of script you're calling. The only variable I can see that needs to be passed is whatever you're using to identify the object being liked. The identity of the _liker_ shouldn't be posted, as that could be anyone. Get this from your PHP session. Where that information comes from is up to you.

Comment: That makes sense, I just dont really understand where the variables are being passed in?